# Recovering a constant salt for MD5

Tags: hash, md5, salt

I have STRING and MD5(STRING+SALT) for any infinitely many STRING's. Is their any way that I can recover the SALT itself? (SALT is constant) I actually know SALT, but this is an intellectual exercise.

Also, I know that the salt is of length 21 and consist of lowercase letters and digits. So there are 36^21 possibilities to enumerate if I just try brute force testing all of the possibilities, which is clearly unreasonable.

Comment: Glad you found the site! I think your question may have been answered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/cracking-secret-key-of-a-md5-hash/20052#20052) and you might be able to find even more using the [search](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/search) function.

Comment: "I know that the hash is of length 21" - "hash" should be "salt", no?

Comment: This question is better written than its duplicate. Oh well...